# How can I add user-based access, customized environments, and a payment feature to my Telegram chatbot using ChatGPT?

Tags: python, customization, chatbot, payment, openai-api

I am currently building a chatbot powered by ChatGPT in Python for Telegram. I want to enhance my chatbot by adding the following features:

User-based access: I need a system to authenticate and authorize users in my chatbot. I want to restrict certain functionalities based on user roles or permissions.

Customized environments: I aim to create personalized experiences for each user by allowing them to customize various settings, such as language preferences, theme choices, or other preferences.

Payment feature: I want to enable a payment feature in my chatbot, where users can make payments for certain services or access premium features. I need to integrate a payment gateway to handle transactions securely.

I have been working on this chatbot for a while and have made progress with the core functionalities. However, I'm facing challenges in implementing these additional features. I am relatively new to Python and would appreciate guidance on how to approach and implement these specific features in my Telegram chatbot.

I tried the maxlimit function created by chatgpt but it didn't seem to work.

I have researched different resources, but I have not been able to find comprehensive examples or tutorials that specifically cover these three features in the context of a ChatGPT-powered chatbot for Telegram. I have explored some Telegram bot libraries and payment gateways, but I need assistance in understanding how to integrate them effectively.

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, Filters, CommandHandler
import telegram
import openai
from moviepy.editor import AudioFileClip
import time

openai.api_key = "KEY"
TELEGRAM_API_TOKEN = "TOKEN"

response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
  model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
  messages=[
    {
      "role": "system",
      "content": "Act as an assistant\n"
    }
  ],
  temperature=1,
  max_tokens=200,
  top_p=1,
  frequency_penalty=0,
  presence_penalty=0,
)

def start(update, context):
    start_message = "What would you like help with today?"
    start_message += "You can ask me to proofread a text, translate a sentence, suggest synonyms, or help with English comprehension. Just type or speak what you need.\n"
    start_message += "You can always type '/help' to explore my features!. \n"
    update.message.reply_text(start_message)

def help_command(update, context):
    help_message = "Here are some of the features you can use:\n\n"
    help_message += "1. Proofread: Send me your text, and I will check it for grammatical errors and suggest improvements\n"
    help_message += "2. Instant Feedback: Share your text with me, and I'll provide immediate feedback on your writing.\n"
    help_message += "3. Writing Analysis: Send your text, and I'll analyze its style, tone, and other aspects.\n"
    help_message += "4. Translation: Provide me with a sentence or paragraph, and I'll translate it into another language\n"
    help_message += "5. Check Word and Character Limit: Send me your text, and I'll provide you with the word and character count.\n"
    help_message += "\n To use any of these features, just start typing your text or send a voice message.\n"
    update.message.reply_text(help_message)

def voice_message(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text("I've received a voice message! Please give me a second to respond :)")
    voice_file = context.bot.getFile(update.message.voice.file_id)
    voice_file.download("voice_message.ogg")
    audio_clip = AudioFileClip("voice_message.ogg")
    audio_clip.write_audiofile("voice_message.mp3")
    audio_file = open("voice_message.mp3", "rb")
    transcript = openai.Audio.transcribe("whisper-1", audio_file).text
    update.message.reply_text(text=f"*[You]:* _{transcript}_", parse_mode=telegram.ParseMode.MARKDOWN)
    messages.append({"role": "user", "content": transcript})
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages=messages,
    )
    ChatGPT_reply = response["choices"][0]["message"]["content"]
    update.message.reply_text(text=f"*[Bot]:* {ChatGPT_reply}", parse_mode=telegram.ParseMode.MARKDOWN)
    messages.append({"role": "assistant", "content": ChatGPT_reply})

def start_timer(duration):
    if "for" in duration:
        # Extract the duration from the phrase
        duration = int(duration.split(" ")[4].split("-")[0])

        # Start the timer
        print(f"Starting the timer for {duration} minutes.")
        time.sleep(duration * 60)
        print("Timer is up!")

updater = Updater(TELEGRAM_API_TOKEN, use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help_command))
dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text & (~Filters.command), text_message))
dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.voice, voice_message))
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.